# Disable Auto-Restart Prompt after Windows Update (in Windows Vista/7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, windows-update, reboot

I've mastered how to [disable/delay the Automatic Restart prompt](http://4sysops.com/archives/disable-restart-after-windows-automatic-updates/) after Windows Update deems it necessary to restart my computer in XP.

But, now I'm using both Windows 7 and Vista and that method no longer works.  So far, I have not been able to circumvent [the Restart Reminder popup](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/6042-windows-update-enable-disable-automatic-restart.html) that keeps telling me *Restart or Postpone decision for 10 min/1 hour/4 hours* (and then popping up again after that delay).  Does anyone know how to delay that popup for something like a day (24 hours) or disable it completely?

Comment: I hate this popup too!

Comment: For Windows 10: [How to *disable* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/957267/301042)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is the solution

http://techie-buzz.com/microblog/postpone-restart-after-windows-update.html

Download page here
http://apps.nozavi.com/downloads/viewcategory/5

Some more solutions in this thread
[Disable restart after update prompt for server 2008 R2](https://superuser.com/questions/190448/disable-restart-after-update-prompt-for-server-2008-r2)

Comment: This disables/stops the Windows Update service which works but also might have side-effects. The other answer is a clean and permanent solution.

Answer (score 20):

An easier way than messing around with the registry, or having to run a command after every update:

Open the Local Group Policy Editor:

> Start / Run / gpedit.msc

Find the Windows Update settings:

> Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components
>   / Windows Update

Edit these 2 settings:

> *No auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations*: Enabled
>
> *Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations*: Enabled, wait period (minutes): 1440

Now you will not be prompted to restart for 24 hours.

Comment: Works in XP, but not Windows 7.

Comment: It works for me in Windows 7

Comment: Home editions of Windows don't have the group policy editor.

Comment: Enable it: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/

Comment: Didn't work for me in Windows 7 SP1 Enterprise in a domain situation.

Comment: This is how it can be done from command line: http://serverfault.com/questions/309905/edit-windows-update-gpo-via-command-line

Comment: Is there a way to completely disable the service rather than just its notification?

Answer (score 4):

You can manually edit the registry using regedit. The best explanation I've found is from the How To Geek here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/prevent-windows-update-from-forcibly-rebooting-your-computer/ The link contains automatic ways I'm posting the manual method here:

> Open up regedit.exe through the start
>   menu search box or run dialog, and
>   navigate down to the following key,
>   creating new keys if they don’t exist.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU
```

[image]

> Create a new 32-bit DWORD value named
>   NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers and give
>   it a value of 1 to prevent automatic
>   reboot while users are logged on.
>   Delete the value to put things back to
>   the way they were.

Comment: This prevents automatic restart but doesn't stop the nagging notification that takes you out of games and full screen video every 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

sc stop wuauserv

see if it stops the nag.

You would need to do this every time you do an update that requires a reboot.

Alternatively, you can go to `Start Menu>Run>regedit`, on the side click `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE>Microsoft>Windows>CurrentVersion>Run`. Once in that folder, right click on the right side of the screen and select `New>String Value`. Name it `"Disable Windows Update Restart Notification"` and in the path type in `"Cmd.exe sc stop wuauserv"` (**without** the quotes, as those indicate a path).

Other suggestions here, this article is for Vista, but maybe some of the reg hacks will work for 7
http://www.tomstricks.com/how-to-disable-the-annoying-windows-update-restart-prompt-in-windows-vista/

Comment: That's true; I have seen that command. But, I was looking for a more permanent solution.

Sadly, I've tried the settings in the article, but even with the settings, the popup persists at least once every four hours.

Comment: Reducing security of a system is never a good answer to solve an annoying user experience.. Your suggestion is to disable Windows Update altogether, which would put the system at risk.

Answer (score 1):

One (and perhaps the easiest way) is to just kill the Windows Update process.

1) Click start menu

2) Type '`cmd`' to the "Search programs and files" and run it by pressing Enter.

3) Change into admin mode by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. (or just run the exe with right click -> Run as administrator)

4) Type `net stop “windows update”`

You can observe that the Windows Update icon disappears from the taskbar, and you will get a text "`The Windows Update service was stopped succesfully`"). This should work in both Windows 7 and Vista.

---

**Note**: The solution is **temporary**. The Windows Update process will come back after you have restarted your computer.

Source: [Howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/uncategorized/temporarily-disable-windows-updates-automatic-reboot-in-vista/)

Answer (score 0):

Save this in a `.reg` file. Run it

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers"=dword:00000001
```