# Disable restart after update prompt for server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-server-2008-r2, automatic-update

I run server 2008 r2 as my desktop OS.

I am trying to disable the annoying restart prompt that comes up after installing updates. The most I can postpone it to is 4 hours.

I have tried disabling “Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations” and enabling “No auto-restart [...] for scheduled Automatic Update installation” in Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update in gpedit.msc, to no avail.

I have looked at various guides, and nothing seems to work.

I do want automatic updates, and I have it set to notify me immediately, and allow me to choose what to download and install. I just don't want this nagger screen to keep coming up, for various reasons.

Is there a fix?

Please don't respond with a lecture about why I should restart automatically, as your assumptions may not be valid.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [Disable Windows Update restart nag](http://lifehacker.com/289998/disable-windows-update-restart-nag):

> To stop this service, open Command
>   Prompt (Start>Run>cmd>Enter) and type
>   the following command `sc stop wuauserv`. This will not prevent
>   Automatic Updates from starting at the
>   next boot. So don't worry, you'll keep
>   getting Windows updates. Just don't
>   forget to restart eventually.

From [disable Automatic Update restart prompts using Windows Computer Policy](http://lifehacker.com/software/top/get-rid-of-windows-update-restart-nag-183976.php)
(was this the one you mentioned in your post?):

> Start / Run / gpedit.msc / `Local Computer Policy / Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Windows Update` / and disable `Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations`.

You can use a freeware product to [Disable Windows Update Restart Alert Message With WindowsUpdateSilencer](http://www.blogsdna.com/4703/disable-windows-update-restart-alert-message-with-windowsupdatesilencer.htm):

> If you want to get rid of Windows
>   Update notification then here is
>   WindowsUpdateSilencer useful tool
>   which runs in the background and will
>   automatically silence all Windows
>   update notifications.

(I have never used this program and can't vouch for it, especially on Server 2008.)

Comment: I'm not interested in stopping the service as a solution, as I am looking for a permanent solution. The group policy solution was indeed the one I tried, and it does not work at all.

Comment: You can push the time limit from 4 hours to 24. See RebootRelaunchTimeout in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708449%28WS.10%29.aspx. You can also do it thru the above policy entry (enabled = 1440 minutes).

Comment: Also see my edit above for WindowsUpdateSilencer.

Comment: Disabling "Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations" only sets the default 10 minutes re-prompt time. With that policy you can go only so far as to postpone by 24 hours (1440 mins)

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](http://4sysops.com/archives/disable-restart-after-windows-automatic-updates/), the correct configuration is to `Enable` the following option:

```
No auto-result with logged on users for scheduled automatic update installations
```

1. Click Start -> Run
2. Enter “gpedit.msc”
3. Go to Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration ->
   Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update
4. Double-click on  “No auto-restart for scheduled Automatic Update
   installation”
5. Enable it!
6. Reboot the computer

As its description clearly meets the goal:

> Specifies that to complete a scheduled installation, Automatic Updates
>   will wait for the computer to be restarted by any user who is logged
>   on, instead of causing the computer to restart automatically.
>
> If the status is set to Enabled, Automatic Updates will not restart a
>   computer automatically during a scheduled installation if a user is
>   logged in to the computer. Instead, Automatic Updates will notify the
>   user to restart the computer.
>
> Be aware that the computer needs to be restarted for the updates to
>   take effect.

Comment: The goal in the question is to disable the prompt, as far as I understand. The quote in your answers says *Automatic Updates will notify the user to restart the computer*, which is what we're trying to stop!

Comment: Looks like this option has been changed to "No auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations". So maybe if no one is logged on it will still reboot?

Comment: @MikeKulls wondering the same thing. --- if my computer is asleep (suspended), will WU still restart? Or does this qualify as being logged in?