# Can't select a "Restart Time"!

Tags: windows-10

Just like "chocochaos" and thunderhue My "select a restart time" is also grayed out.

It is very frustrating that there does not seem to be an answer to this problem.

I just want to set my own restart time!!!

Comment: say what now???

Comment: Hi James.  We have no idea what you're referencing (I'm assuming it's http://superuser.com/questions/963998/can-not-select-a-restart-time?rq=1). :)  You may want to [take the tour](http://superuser.com/tour) to figure out how the Stack Exchange sites work.  Also maybe check out the [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) help topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually run a shutdown or restart timer by the following:

Press `Win` + `R`

For a shutdown timer:

`shutdown -s -t NUMBER_OF_SECONDS`

For restarting:

`shutdown -r -t NUMBER_OF_SECONDS`

As an example, if you want your computer to shut down completely in one hour, you'd type this in the `Run...` window:

`shutdown -s -t 3600`