# Is NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers still supported/effective on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, windows-update

Note: something similar has a good answer here [How to *disable* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10). This is not the same because I'm explicitely looking for information about a different option.

Plain and simple question: Is [NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939923%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (registry value) still supported/effective on Windows 10? This option is gold for me, because it allows complete and automatic updates installation (as per default) but prevents the autoreboot step.

The [equivalent](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779747(v=ws.10).aspx) *no auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations* gpedit policy is present, so I would expect NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers to be supported too.

[image]

I'm getting mixed feedback after NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers is applied: someone says it's effective, someone reports not. Is there a semi-official reference for it?

Thanks!

Comment: According to this article it is still supported in W10...http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-rebooting-for-update-installations/

Comment: Also check Gpedit settings....http://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/17530-disable-automatic-reboot-updates.html

Comment: One way to confirm it is to try the registry setting on a test machine...

Comment: Possible solution here....https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3h6e74/how_do_i_stop_windows_10_from_automatically/

Comment: Have you heeded the note at the end of the description? The one about "Configure Automatic Updates".

Comment: The registry keys and their behavior is fully documented at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart#delay-automatic-reboot though that is written for enterprise deployments; not sure if this can be applied in the same way to regular consumer installations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I found out that `NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers` **is not sufficient**. The corresponding gpedit policy, `No auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations`, clearly states that the setting has no effect unless `Configure automatic update` is also set.

This is my writeup (*in italian, sorry*) on the matter:

[Guida Windows 10: come impedire il riavvio automatico per l'installazione degli aggiornamenti](https://turbolab.it/manutenzione-156/guida-windows-10-come-impedire-riavvio-automatico-installazione-aggiornamenti-843)

For those interested: a ready-to-use `.reg` with all the needed settings to prevent automatic reboots is here:

[Disabilita riavvio automatico Windows Update](https://turbolab.it/manutenzione-156/guida-windows-10-come-impedire-riavvio-automatico-installazione-aggiornamenti-843)

Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: Thank  you for this!  I put a slightly modified version here:  http://www.geeksalive.com/NoAutoReboot_Win10.zip

Comment: @DaveBurton what's the point of additional "NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers"?

Comment: @vanown sorry, I don't recall. 

They are at two different keys/locations: 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU] and 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update] 

Maybe they were for different versions of Windows? Sorry.

Comment: I have found this doesn't work in Windows 11. I woke up to find my PC had restated at 3:15am with `The process C:\WINDOWS\uus\AMD64\MoUsoCoreWorker.exe (COMPUTERNAME) has initiated the restart of computer COMPUTERNAME on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Service pack (Planned)` in the event log.

Answer (score -1):

According to my tests, it can be set in Group policy, but is ignored by MusNotification which controls reboot after update. See this posts

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/my-work-lost-after-window-10-nightly-restart-for/e55c0399-5fad-4e64-b3c4-301838a1d5f6?auth=1

[https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7253eaef-2ea8-42c8-8bda-0bdb0a284847/wsus-and-win10-auto-reboot-behavior?forum=winserverwsus](https://web.archive.org/web/20220627180207/https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7253eaef-2ea8-42c8-8bda-0bdb0a284847/wsus-and-win10-auto-reboot-behavior?forum=winserverwsus)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.