# How to postpone the restart for "It's almost time to restart" by more than one hour?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, reboot

I use Windows 10 Pro and I got a "It's almost time to restart" message. How can I postpone the restart by more than one hour?

[image]

Windows automatic updates are supposed to be disabled:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the Windows forcefully rebooting after an *automatic* update:

Use [Local Group Policy Editor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn265982(v=ws.11)) to set [*Configure Automatic Updates*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart) enabled.

- Run `gpedit.msc`
- Navigate to **Local Computer Policy** → **Computer Configuration** → **Administrative Templates** → **Windows Components** → **Windows Update**
- Enable the **Configure Automatic Updates** policy

  - Set **Configure automatic updating** to `4 - Auto download and schedule the install`
  - Enable the **No auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates** policy

### Alternatively

You also configure the above options through the registry

- Launch **regedit.exe**
- Navigate to `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU`
- set:

  - **AuOptions** = `4`
  - **NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers** = `1` (i.e., true)

  [image: Prevent auto reboot while logged on]

**N.B.** If you manually start the update process, Windows may still reboot while your logged on.

For more information on controlling updates *via* Group Policy, see
[Manage additional Windows Update settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-wu-settings).