# How to open the group policy editor on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I am attempting to disable automatic reboots in windows 10, but looking at the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10), I find I fail at the first hurdle because I can't even open the group policy editor.

I then found [this](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/5-ways-to-access-local-group-policy-editor-on-windows-10.html), but none of those options seemed to work. For example of I type the word "group" into the windows search, I only see this:

[image]

If I actually type the two words "group policy" then I get "No results found for 'group policy'"

Looking on my HDD I can see that there are four instances of gpedit.msc in some very strangely named directories:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try windows key + r and type gpedit.msc

This will run the manager.

Comment: I get "Windows cannot find 'gpedit.msc'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."

Comment: @Mick Do you have the home or pro version of windows 10?

Comment: Its only the home version.

Comment: @Mick Aye.. The home version doesnt have group policies. Only the pro and enterprise versions.

Comment: AAAARrrrggggghhh!

Comment: @Mick but are the automatic reboots from windows updates? Take a look at this http://superuser.com/questions/1112380/disable-automatic-restarts-in-windows-10-home-anniversary-update

Comment: I don't understand how that answer suggests anything other than a reboot caused by a windows update... anyway, if you edit in the fact that windows 10 home does not have a group policy editor then I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @Mick well reboots dont occur randomly they happen for a reason. Well it can be any form of reboot. But keep in mind that Group policies only edit register entries. So on home you can still go in the Regedit and change it. Making it kinda a group policy.

Comment: [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](//superuser.com/a/1018146)

Comment: @Mick or try that.