# How to Cancel or Prevent Windows 10 from rebooting my PC?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

This may be, after decades of Windows use, the moment when I switch to Mac...

Issue: Win is rebooting my PC, once or twice a day, once when I was on a phone call, with a word doc in front of me, discussing it by tel.

I believe the core issue is that the big update to Win 10 is failing to install properly.

I followed the steps here: https://superuser.com/a/963933/15466  But the reboots continue.

The GUI currently shows as below.

a) How do a PREVENT auto reboots, in general?

b) How do I STOP the reboot that the system is telling me will occur in the next hour?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you connected to a domain? If so, your domain administrators might have forced this behavior. "Some settings are managed ny your organization" in your screen shot suggests that.

Answer (score 0):

You can defer reboots with the dialog you have in your first image: schedule for a later time.  You cannot put them off forever, though, eventually it will force the issue.  If it is rebooting daily trying to fix a broken/failing update, this may not even work, and you should really work that out or it might get worse.

There are various ways to slow down or more strongly defer update downloads and installs, or stop them entirely, but this is obviously not recommended as you'll be deferring/missing security updates.

You can set your interface to Metered mode, [even an ethernet connection](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/how-to-set-an-ethernet-connection-as-metered-to/ecdaca08-d413-4a6a-9e33-b4afb337fc18?auth=1).  This will prevent it from downloading a lot, but I believe it will still push 'priority' security updates.  Not sure about other stuff.

You can also disable Windows Update entirely via the Services administration panel, but that's very not-recommended (and probably unwise).

Comment: The above is incorrect, sorry. I CANNOT defer the reboot.... it is going to do it as soon as system is idle. That is what I am trying to manage.