# How to *disable* automatic reboots in Windows 10 Home (January 2017)

Tags: windows-10

I wish to prevent windows from rebooting after doing an update because sometimes I want to leave my PC performing a task unattended for days on end.

Now before you rush to tell me this is a duplicate of [this other SO question](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10), I should point out that A) Most of the (very long) most upvoted answer is devoted to more premium versions of Windows which includes gpedit which Home does not have. B) There are a lot of comments about solutions not working and this may well be date dependant, i.e. some solutions perhaps *used* to work but don't any more. I think this issue is so important that this question needs to be asked again so that the up/down votes will correspond to the *current* state of play.

I would also like to add an additional part of the question which is - once I have made the changes necessary to prevent forced reboots, is there some way of telling that I have done it correctly? I.e. some place in windows where it will actually tell me that future reboots have been disabled.

By the way I am asking this question now because I did attempt to follow the prevent-reboot solutions from a variety of sources but my PC rebooted itself last night (12 Jan 2017).

**ANSWER FOUND:** This is a simple solution that works: [windows-10-reboot-blocker](http://www.udse.de/en/windows-10-reboot-blocker).

Comment: What is the actual question ? W10H does not automatically reboot.

Comment: @Overmind: See edit to first sentence.

Comment: Don't connect it to the internet so you don't get updates or get a version which allows you to postpone etc.. There won't be any indicator as there are other sources of reboots as well. You can't disable reboots altogether.

Comment: Good idea Seth, but sometimes my task requires an internet connection.

Comment: You can't.  In 1703 due in May you will be able to defer updates for 35 days but only in Professional and above.  Answers that require using gpedit are applicable to Home, since you can manually put, goedit on Home

Comment: @Ramhound: interesting... http://gizmodo.com/microsoft-might-finally-kill-automatic-windows-10-updat-1790565593

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \*disable\* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10).  The answer to the duplicate can still be done on Windows 10 Home, due to [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](http://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i), which is an acceptable answer until 1703 is released.  After 1703, the actual feature, will be limited to Professional and above without a work around

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit barbaric, but it's the only thing I could think of...

Create a scheduled task to run **shutdown.exe -a** (which cancels every reboot command in progress) every 10 minutes or so. For example:

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 20 /tn "Don't Reboot" /tr "shutdown -a"
```