# Will windows 10 interrupt a running .bat file for automatic restarts?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, updates

I run nighly .bat files which handle needed tasks.
Will windows 10 eventually interrupt them while they are running for an automatic restart in order to install updates? Or is it smart enough to see something is going on and waits for a better moment?

Comment: Why don't you reboot during the day then so the nightly automation of batch scripts run? I'd think that would pacify the concern here for a simple solution. Since you know batch scripting well, look over my answer here for a way to control the restart time but read over the entire post so you understand what it does and how it works.... https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/1208866#1208866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will absolutely interrupt and restart! There are always processes running on computers, so it interrupts all of those as well without a care in the world. The workaround is add 2 lines to your batch file to temporarily turn off the Update service..

net stop “windows update” (at the beginning of the batch)
net start “windows update” (at the end of the batch)