# Stopping automatic restarts - windows 10

Tags: windows, reboot

I perform data acquisition over long periods (months). Auto restart after a windows update closes the data acquisition software and therefore stops the data acquisition. How can I prevent these restarts until it is convenient for me.

Thanks Phil

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \*disable\* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

Phil

Some interesting information here ... might help you

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: First of all, Welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please do not provide answers that are only a hyperlink.  While the information may be valuable, if the source web page ever goes offline the answer is essentially useless.  Quote all of the pertinent excerpts from the article within your answer, then you can still provide the hyperlink to cite your source.   Please see the following article from our Help Center:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Toto, on the other hand, this is one of the few or only answers which point to the official documentation. All other answers often just mention "edit registry key X", leaving the reader wondering what the key actually does. For example the current version of the linked documentation mentions that `NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers` on its own might not have any effect; an important detail which most answers to duplicates of this question miss.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is the same answer as @afkg*

The automatic reboot after a Windows update can be disabled from the [Local Group Policy Editor](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/79976-open-local-group-policy-editor-windows-10-a.html) (gpedit.msc). 
Go to `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Update` and activate the `No auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations` policy.

In case you can't access the Group Policy Editor (because your Windows 10 edition isn't Pro, Enterprise or Education), you can do it from the Registry Editor (regedit). 
Go to `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU` and set the key `NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers` to `1`.

*While the link provided by @afkg gives complete and detailed information about a solution, it may become broken as pointed out by @Toto. I extracted the essential information and put it in this answer (at least, it was enough for my case).