# Forced reboot/update on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, reboot

I'm having a nightmarish life due to windows policy change where I can't delay the automatic update.

The symptom I'm having is that I leave my station for few moment only to come back to find that windows on a "mandated" update and I can't touch my computer for prolonged period of time. I know it is my fault for not saving, but if I can't use the computer at all...

I feel like there should be a solid answer at least to be alert of this forced update before it actually happens. My googling skill so far have failed to yield positive result over the past few month.

I've tried

1. Setting task scheduler to disable reboot of update orchest(...)
2. Changing active hours (max 18hr )
3. not using hibernation but sleep (sometime hibernation force update when waking up from hibernation even though window menu doesn't say so)
4. regularly checking for update so it wouldn't jump on me
5. ignoring any "install" button as I assume that auto force reboot
6. Having a blank speed throttled torrent on (so far this works best)

System spec: all windows 10, but differing hardware spec from $100 laptop to workstation to gaming system.
 ps. I've gotten into habit of saving code work every 30 sec, but I still lose work layout (windows, pages, apps, server connection)

Comment: You make it sound like this is an absolutely horrible, persistent thing that is happening to you when that is absolutely false. Not a single Windows 10 machine I have forces a reboot on me like that. At worst they reboot themselves in the middle of the night when I’m not using them once every week or two. Most of the time Windows opens all my stuff back up for me. Once I almost couldn’t tell the system had rebooted. Save your stuff and stop acting like this is some crazy ridiculous thing happening.

Comment: Whose "policy change"? If it's your employer that made this decision, take it up with IT staff.

Comment: Try this solution since it sounds like you are a local admin of the machine. I assume you are referring to "policy" as some hidden behind the scene Windows spooky vudu trick and NOT a corporate IT policy as in Group Policies and WSUS updates and such: https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/1208866#1208866