# How to prevent automatic reboot

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8

System updates are good and one should not avoid them. Company policy do address that.

There are couple of computers that shall disobey such rule for a damn good reason.

Is there a way how to prevent automatic scheduled updates and reboots and prevent remote administration to reenforce this regime back?

Comment: *"Company policy..."*  We are always glad to help, but if this is a corporate computer you really need to consult your IT support staff.  The volunteers who donate their expertise to the Super User community shouldn't be utilized to circumvent the policies that your IT professionals enforce.

Comment: This question only applies to Windows 10, W7 and 8 can easily avoid this issue.

Comment: If the company is applying the patches then the company can use whatever system they push the patches with to exclude the computers that you don't want them pushed to.

Comment: @EBGreen "If" that is a big word, we have no clue that their IT staff is doing, that is why it is off topic here.

Comment: Oh, I completely agree that it is off-topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \*disable\* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10)

Comment: @Run5k Thank you for your comment. The computers are corporate ones but they were delivered as a part of analytical device rather than personal computers.

Answer (score 1):

FIrst off, Run5k's comment is correct.  If these are corporate systems, and you are *not* the responsible IT administrator for them, you need to talk to the responsible IT administrator for these systems about this.  Assuming you convince that person that you really do need these system to not reboot on their own, feel free to point them at this answer for an explanation of one way to do that.

Second, there are very few cases that you're likely to convince any seasoned IT professional that these systems need to both not reboot on their own when an update hits, *and* not handle updates as part of regular maintenance during scheduled downtime.  There are only two cases I can think of that need such a setup, long-running operations being left to run overnight, and people who insist on leaving everything open as a reminder of what they were doing instead of using more reasonable methods.  The first one is trivially solved by just pausing updates when you start the operation, and I have zero respect for the second one as it's not a reliable method to achieve their desired effect even without automatic reboots for updates.

Now, with all of that out of the way, you can get some configurations similar to the old Windows 7 update options through the use of group policy.  The relevant entry is in the Windows Update subsection of the Windows Components section of the Administrative Templates, and is called 'Configure Automatic Updates'.  Settings of 2 and 3 can be used to require manual installation, which means in turn that the system won't reboot by itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Option one is correct - we do often setup schedules over night or over weekend. For the second option I have very same respect as you do.