# Computer keeps restarting and I swear I've tried everything

Tags: windows-10, crash

Computer info at the end.

My computer started restarting at seemingly random times yesterday, and I have no clue why. I've tried:

- Restart the computer
- Reinstall GPU drivers
- Virus scan
- System Restore
- Reinstall Windows on a different, new drive
- Run Memtest86 (no errors found)
- Run the computer with just one of my two RAM sticks (tried with each stick individually, no change)
- Reseat all PSU cable connections
- Replace GPU

I have no idea what causes it. Sometimes it's when I'm playing games. Sometimes it's when I'm browsing the web. Sometimes it's when the OS is starting after a cold boot. I haven't had any crashes while using the computer in safe mode, but I don't know if that's coincidence or not, because the amount of time it takes for the computer to restart is somewhere between 10 seconds and several hours. I've checked my event logs - nothing. It just says that the computer shut down unexpectedly. I looked for a minidump - nothing. It shuts down too suddenly; there's no BSOD. This computer has been sitting in the same exact location for probably 5 months now, save for one or two small adjustments over the last couple months. No problems until *yesterday*. I hadn't installed any new programs or downloaded anything.

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Build 1511 (OS Build 10586.318)
- CPU: Ryzen 5 1600
- RAM: 16 GB (8x2) G.Skill Trident Z RGB (tested with each 8GB stick individually)
- Mobo: Asus Prime X370-Pro
- GPU: Nvidia GTX 1070 (also tried GTX 970)
- Storage: 500GB WD Black M.2 (also tried with 250GB OCZ Vector-180). 1TB Caviar Black HDD for storage.

Running two monitors at 1440p if that matters.

PSU: I believe I have a 650W PSU rated at Bronze. I'll see if I can get more specific info.

I have no idea what to look into next. It's still restarting. Event viewer is still providing exactly zero useful evidence as far as I can tell.

Additionally, it just restarted while I had Speccy open, so I was also able to rule out temps - CPU was in the mid-30s and GPU was in the mid-40s.

Comment: Have you updated your hardware recently?

Comment: 650W is the **minimum** I would use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks to me like a power supply issue. I'll explain:

Some processess get really heavy on performance demands, like gaming and yes, today's browsers when visiting some pages and/or having several of them loaded and running. This demands relapse on the power supply, which has to serve every component it's required power in a stable way. If demands are greater than the supply's capabilities, some components (most vulnerable to this are CPU and RAM) won't get the power they need causing them to fail.

In your case, I would monitor the power supply's voltages - each value should be very nearly it's nominal value or over it (3,3 should be around that or greater, for instance). If any of them gets low when demanding power (when playing, 3,3 goes around 2,9, for instance again), that's your faulty component. I usually see failing power supplies when the 12v line goes around 11.something (a brand new one usually gives 12.3v). Also, just to be sure, [disable automatic reboots](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/) to at least see how windows register the reboot, because this kind of fault is also common when facing failing CPUs and/or RAM sticks. Good luck.

Comment: You were super close. Long story short, it WAS an issue with the PSU, but apparently it was something as simple as the connector at the PSU side was loose (it's a modular unit). I checked all the connections on the mobo end of things, but not on the PSU end.

Comment: Thanks for the update, and I'm glad to read you solved it!