# How to prevent system updates on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Quite simply.

I would like to prevent updates on my windows 10 system from happenning.
Before any body asks why? Because it is incredibly stupid and damaging thing done by those idiots at microsoft.
The problem is that updates happen at random time, restarting the computer with no regard what so ever if something is running on a computer and no option to postpone or cancel.

Example:
We have run an important data transformation and import into database. The process took many hours and we have left computer to do its job. What happened... the update. Our batch job was interrupted, data was corrupted, database was left in inconsistent state nad worst of all, the data was not even available at our source any more.

Comment: Check out this post that allows you to control when the reboot happens: https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/1208866#1208866 without circumventing the security patching. There are additional answers there as well with other related solutions and such too.... This may actually work out better for you per the language of your question when read entirely

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in command prompt:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU" /v NoAutoUpdate /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU" /v AUOptions /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU" /v ScheduledInstallDay /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU" /v ScheduledInstallTime /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f
```

Taken from here: https://github.com/adolfintel/Windows10-Privacy#no-more-forced-updates

This will never prompt you for an update, it will all be entirely down to the user. Updates will not be downloaded unless you request to download them in the settings. On top of that they will not install or prompt to install unless the user does so.