# It's 2019, How to *disable* automatic reboots and updates in Windows 10? Old methods are no longer working

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates, automatic-update

Many of the solutions to prevent windows 10 from doing their auto reboot updates are not working anymore. The solutions posted here:

**No, this question is not a duplicate.** Hence: **"It's 2019"**

[How to *disable* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10)

Are outdated and just a waste of time for everyone to try as they do NOT work anymore. It's 2019, what tricks does Microsoft have up their sleeves to force an auto shutdown update?

Many people seeking help want to disable updates completely. Not just auto reboot. Please do not post answers that only disable auto reboot. Alot of the times when windows update with new patches, it removes certain programs that it deems unnecessary. In my case it constantly removes my work's vpn software. wtf!? I just want to disable updates completely!

What are the latest ways of preventing further updates on Windows 10? Home and Pro versions. Solutions that don't need to install software would be best, but also installing 3rd party software can be possible too for the non-tech savvy.

Comment: I'd like to comment that, I really hate windows 10 because of its auto updates. But i have to use it for work... =(

Comment: We are always glad to help, but there are a *lot* of answers within that referenced question with numerous up-votes.  At the risk of posing an obvious question, did you actually try all of them before you dismissed them as "outdated and a waste of time for everyone?"  For example, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1208866/650163) was recently awarded a bounty for being an outstanding contribution, so that would seem to imply that it works rather well.  Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I did... did you look at when it was written? **answered May 13 '17 at 16:15** and do you use Windows 10? Did you know they just had an updated pushed out a few days ago? Microsoft has bypassed these tricks. We need a new upto date answer and not shift through all those outdated ones that is a complete waste of time and misleads people to try it.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I manage three domains that encompass more than 12,000 Windows 10 Enterprise workstations (as well as maintaining eight Windows 10 Pro machines on my home network), so I guess you could say that I use Windows 10.

Comment: Great. But I doubt you disable updates as your in a "work" environment. They want the auto updates. For us individuals, its extremely problematic. I just lost my college design work cuz this stupid thing restarted while I was sleeping. And now I need to figure out how to reinstall my work's VPN software, cuz these updates constantly removes this software for some unknown reason.

Comment: The only way I can see is to disable the windows update service, enable it when you are ready to install updates and restart the system. I have been using a windows update minitool i got on the internet in 2016, it still works with 1809, but it is no longer available....https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-update-minitool.380535/

Comment: That's quite old.  it still works? i have windows build 17134 Where can I download it? thanks

Comment: Just as a comment: Saving your files would have prevented the data loss. Windows needs to self-manage, and you CAN define work hours to prevent it from performing the self-maintenance tasks during the times you're likely to be using it. Rather than blaming the OS for taking good care of itself, be more careful to save your work. Also, talk to your work about why their VPN software keeps being removed on updates. They either have a fix for that, or they need to figure out a fix for it.

Comment: Since you state "But i have to use it for work," this should be an issue for your IT department, not you. If you make an arbitrary, unapproved, change the OS, IT would **not** be amused.

Comment: I'm a freelancer. There is no such thing as an IT department. @DrMoishePippik not everyone works in a corporate place like you.

Comment: I use Winaero Tweaker, which is very popular and aggressively tries to keep up-to-date with Microsoft's attempts to force you to install updates.

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ, then why are you forced to use Windows? Are you using proprietary software that does not run under wine or have a Linux equivalent?

Comment: Are you certain you tried.... https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/1208716#1208716 ? That should do the trick natively but I wanted to see if you confirm you indeed verified that solution did not work? You say "*do not post answers that only disable auto reboot*" and "*I just want to disable updates completely*", I assume you want a solution that does just that only.

Comment: The correct course is not to say "The old question is wrong, let's have a 2019 edition!" If the old question has answers that no longer work then you can comment or raise a bounty. One of the specific bounty reasons is "Current answers are outdated" which would be a good way to get the community involved in resolving issues.

Comment: @Mokubai - Unless an admin can come along and un-accept the accepted answer, that's not a functional approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tool from Greatis (https://greatis.com/blog/stopupdates10) lets you turn updates on and off easily, I've been using it for quite awhile. After an update's been released I wait for all the crap to get sorted out, you know, things like it deleting ALL your personal files, then install the update once it's been fixed.

Comment: thanks. is this software safe to use? i dont want malware or trojans. that site looks shady.

Comment: Warnings: https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/greatis.com

Comment: This is working for me. StopUpdates10 is what I'm using now. https://greatis.com/stopupdates10/#changelog

Comment: I would stay away from that product, Greatis definitely collects a bunch of data from its users. Here is an excerpt from Greatis TOS:

(g) Data collection.
Greatis Software collects diagnostic information for debugging purposes, and anonymous usage analytics of our apps ... You agree that Greatis Software collect, use, store and transmit technical and related information that identifies your computer (including Internet Protocol Address), operating system, application usage and error reports that may be gathered ...