# Specify Windows update restart time

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2016

I'm running a few Windows Server machines and have set the active hours under Windows Update settings but the actual restart time seems to be random under default settings.

Is there a way to set when the OS (Windows Server 2016/2019/10) can restart unattended?

For example: server 1 restarts at 1am, server 2 restarts at 2am, server 3 restarts at 3am, etc.

Basically, I want to avoid more than 1 machines restarting at the same time. Is there a better way to manage this?

Comment: “server 1 restarts at 1am, server 1 restarts at 2am, server 1 restarts at 3am” - What?  If Active Hours works inconsistent, schedule the reboot, for a specific time.  What purpose does these servers serve.  As always edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: So your example isn’t the random behavior but what you actually want to have happen?  You can either choose a period of time where you are active (Activity Hours) or choose a specific time to reboot the machine.

Comment: You need to clarify your question by editing it

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify exactly what you want to have happened.  Outside of using WSUS you might have to accept the limitations provided out of the box. Which of course are a window of time outside of the Activity Hours and a specific scheduled time.  If you were to offset the Activity Hours you might accomplish what you want.  You can also automate the schedule time with a PowerShell script

Comment: “I want to set it once so it would restart at that specific time, every time there's an update that requires a server restart.” - This option does not exist specifically.  What you can do is have a script that runs automatically and schedules the reboot.  You can either set the registry key or the applicable group policy.  [ScheduledInstallTime](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/1208866#1208866) should be your solution to your problem

Comment: this looks promising. i can just set the active hours for server 1: 2am-1am, server 2 3am-2am...

Comment: Either run a script every X Hours that sets the applicable registry key for the Activity Hours, or since your using Windows Server, set a specific install time, you will accomplish pretty much the same thing.  Treating this as a sort of duplicate of that question since you want to prevent automatic reboots caused by Windows Update, and the duplicates answer, allows you to do that (with minor modifications)