# How can I prevent Microsoft Windows 10 from displaying the "let's cross this one off your list" update pop-up?

Tags: windows-10, updates

How can I prevent Microsoft Windows 10 from displaying "let's cross this one off your list" update pop-up? (without having to update Microsoft Windows 10)

[image]

I use Microsoft Windows 18.03.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \*disable\* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10).  See the answer with the bounty

Comment: What you basically do it’s continuously schedule the update for a future time

Comment: Click `Restart Now` and the message will go away.

Comment: @Appleoddity I have some servers running on it: I don't want to restart.