# How to stop Windows reboot?

Tags: windows, reboot, automatic-update

There has been variety of solutions offered using some script or playing with the registry. Is there a way to stop auto-update and auto-reboot of Windows? How can a person not from a programming background stop reboot?

Comment: In what circumstances?

Comment: It's not recommended. The software which initiates the reboot process initiates it without any delay. So ever in case when you send a command to OS to stop this process some sevices (which already receives the STOP signal) can stop their work - it can produce unstable system work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \*disable\* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10)

Comment: Circumstances could be anything, like it does an auto-update and then reboots without checking with the user. How is it relevant to the question?
As I described in the question I was hoping for some solution much simpler than playing around with registry.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick fix on some blog to set internet to metered connection. This will stop auto-update and auto-reboot. It is not the best but could be helpful. It might disable some other apps. For the moment it solves the main problem of rebooting without asking the user.