# Coordinate Windows Update with Service

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have a Windows machine that is normally unattended, compiling software under the control of Jenkins. Windows Update occasionally reboots that machine, which aborts all running compiles, causing error reports to be sent out.

Is there a way to coordinate with the Windows Update service?

Requirements

- detect that an update is pending so no new builds are scheduled on this node
- hold off the update until all running jobs are complete
- immediately trigger the update as soon as the node is idle

It is acceptable if the "hold off the update" option has a time limit of a few hours -- our longest build takes about five hours normally, and up to ten if the machine is under load.

Comment: Here's an answer for one part of your question (https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/1208866#1208866) but the others I'm not too sure about other than timing those processes out and then settings some policies to always install updates and immediately reboot once those complete. So for example if you can tell the node processes on the applicable machines to not run between 7:45 PM and 8:45 PM, you can schedule the updates to always start on this specific day every week at a specific time and reboot immediately afterwards. All I can think of atm.