# Windows 10 update repeating daily

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, scheduled-tasks

Sounds like a noob question but is a serious problem. Due to updates for I guess Windows Defender my local machine wants to update daily. It is even interrupting processes and shuting down the system of its own. I know security is important but this is no option for me because it makes the system almost useless.

As far as I know I can disable Windows updates by setting `NoAutoUpdate` (`REG_DWORD`) to true in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows`. But then I might forget updating the system at all, I wish I could set an automatic cronjob one or two times in a month. Is there a possibility to set this somehow?

(Do not close, the correct answer is in the comments)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \*disable\* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10)

Comment: Find out why this is happening (watch the update process) Windows Defender updates are painless, non-invasive , and do not require restarts. Other Windows 10 updates are roughly monthly

Comment: @K7AAY This is indeed the correct answer, there was a problem with some software which made Windows updates failed but they tried over and over again. You can make an answer of this I will accept, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windows Update repeats daily, most likely it has a failed update, and it is retrying it in hope that a new version of the update is released which can get past the problem.  For you to solve it, look in Windows Update, and if there's a recurring failing update, search on the web, starting with Microsoft's website, for the cause of the failure.

Comment: In my case it was Veracrypt 1.21 which was blocking the updates (very stupid from my part, why did I never check the build version). For updating with this version of Veracrypt you had to decrypt the system for updating. This problem was fixed in Veracrypt 1.23 and updwards.