# Is there any way I can delay an already installed Windows update until next week?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows Update said there was a new security update so I installed it. It took far longer than usual to download. I walked away from the computer for a while and the screen-capture here shows what *actually* happened.

How can I delay the reboot until next week?

The dropdown only gives me the choice of the next six (6) days.

[image: Microsoft bait-and-switch]

Comment: Set it to reboot in 6 days, and in 5 days, head to settings->updates-> plan reboot, and set a new time.

Comment: Also, most of us (all who I know) can allow the update to occur overnight, so also set OFF Hours in Update Settings.

Comment: @LPChip: Didn't know that it could be bumped like that, thanks for the info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to \*disable\* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10)

Comment: @John:  I did not want to have to deal with any update-related issues that particular week, as I was working on a very time-sensitive project. Perhaps you have not had the pleasure of having your PC adversely affected by an update?

Comment: In addition to setting OFF hours (a normally permanent setting), you can pause updates for up to 7 days. You need to do this setting in advance because once updates are waiting for a restart, no other updates can happen. Most of us can deal with overnight updates.

Comment: @John. Often I fall into that blessed "most of us" category chock-full of happy campers. But sometimes I do not. It depends on what's going on at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the option of stopping the services responsible for all of this... sort of.

The whole restart circus is managed by the update orchestrator service if I remember correctly. The problem with these services is that they tend to restart themselves without your permission even if disabled.

There are different ways to prevent it from restarting, although none are 100%. You can disable the service, you can change the service's permissions in the registry so that only you can change the service's status (that way only you can re-enable it - at least theoretically). You can also rename the service's DLL, although I can't guarantee that it won't break anything significant, and you may have to do it with a third-party file browser since explorer may refuse to do it.

And I've even seen Windows 10 recreate the Windows Update service DLL out of thin air.

The services, as far as I know, that manage the whole update process are:

- wuauserv: Windows Update Service
- UsoSvc: Update Orchestrator Service
- WaaSMedicSvc: Windows Update Medic Service

I can't guarantee, though, that there aren't more there - Microsoft seems kind of intent on hiding these services from people wanting control over their computer.

Of course, there are always options like O&O ShutUp10 that can manage this for you.

Finally, the obligatory warning: Whatever you do, don't forget to re-enable all of this stuff at some point, because security updates are important, after all (even though this ended up being a feature update instead).

Comment: “There are different ways to prevent it from restarting, although none are 100%.” - Incorrect; There is a 100% method submitted as an answer to the duplicate question.  Furthermore, registry hacks and third-party software, are unnecessary to prevent these automatic reboots.  Leveraging the feature to delay the reboot is enough, now eventually you really should perform the update, but I personally have delayed an update for weeks at a time.