# How to permanently disable any Windows 10 automatic updates that aren't directly crucial to the integrity of my operating system

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates, windows-store-app, auto-updates

My PC is always low on space, and for the longest time I kept wondering why my C: drive kept filling up even though I wasn't downloading anything, and finally I discovered TreeSize and found out that pretty much every time space was taken up it was because of some automatic Windows-related update.

Today I found out I could disable Windows Store updates by going to their settings, but I'm not sure that will prevent other Windows 10-related apps from automatically updating like Minecraft Windows 10 Edition or Microsoft Edge or Microsoft Onedrive or Windows Store itself, which I was surprised to see have a completely UI today after not touching it for month.

---

**TL;DR** I need to permanently disable any Windows 10 automatic updates that aren't directly crucial to the integrity of my operating system. ie. Microsoft Edge, Windows Store games, etc.

For bonus, I'd just like to completely disable automatic updates from any big services I have installed on my computer, like Adobe, Google, and such.

Comment: Stop using Windows 10 or 11.  Other permanently stopped everything CANNOT be done and SHOULD not be done.

Comment: @Moab Does that option stop updates for all Windows-related things? Like for example Microsoft Edge updates, Onedrive (I don't even use Onedrive), Minecraft Windows 10 edition, etc.? I'd like a little bit more control than that, as I would like to still receive automatic updates from crucial things like maybe time syncing or something else I don't know about.

Comment: Not as far as I know. The only way to disallow Windows 10 from ALL updates is to turn it off.

Comment: @John Your sarcastic replies aren't helping me at all... Besides I never said I wanted to turn off ALL updates, did you read the title?

Comment: It is not sarcastic.  All Windows and all Windows APPs update themselves. Hence my reply. Again, not sarcastic at all. I find your overall thesis to be entirely untenable.

Comment: Try WUMT https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/Windows_update_minitool.html  However I have not personally used it, so do not know if it's effective. Otherwise try in a VM first and then decide.

Comment: I think you are stuck.  There is no differentiating from one patch vs another what part to keep via automatic updates.  Keep in mind that apps include things that might provide a vulnerability to the operating system itself.  Linux works the same.  Apple works the same.  I know.. I am not preaching Microsoft.. it simply is the way that it is.

Comment: @patkim The only reply on that tool says it doesn't work on Windows 10.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Alright then... Could I disable updates from each Windows 10 software individually? The ones I listed (Onedrive, Microsoft Edge, Minecraft Windows 10 edition, Microsoft Store (the app itself) ) can be a start.

Comment: I suggest two things: First get a much bigger disk. These are inexpensive. Once done figure out what you really need to do. Near everyone wants and needs bug fixes and anyone who has lost their data to viruses needs security updates.  Then delete this question and ask one that is focused and that makes sense to a wide audience. Being short on disk is quickly and easily fixed

Comment: "Does that option stop updates for all Windows-related things?" - Microsoft Edge isn't updated through Windows Update, OneDrive would be updated through Microsoft Store but you can easily remove that particular application if you want. The linked duplicate provides a method, to contously postpone the installation of updates, which is the only method that works on Windows 10+ It is not possible to disable WIndows Update on WIndows 10+ otherwise, unless, you are running Enterprise and Education and have installed a LTS version. Minecraft is update through Xbox application

Comment: You can also postpone cumulative updates by setting a policy.  This will in combination of the duplicate, postpone Windows Updates from being installed until you are ready to handle their installation[.](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10). Setting up a fake WSUS likely is your best bad solution to NOT updating Windows which is a REALLY bad idea.

Comment: @Ramhound can you explain why "Setting up a fake WSUS" is a bad idea? What even is a WSUS? How do I postpone Windows Updates? Also, my question didn't ask to only disable Windows Update, I was asking to disable all non-crucial Windows-related updates such as Minecraft Windows 10 Addition - Plus other things like Dropbox, Adobe, or Google

Comment: @asgasehswheeshss - You want to disable WIndows Updates, that is a bad idea, there is an answer to the duplicate questions that explains has a step that configures a fake WSUS.  It would be up to you to download and push updates through WSUS if you went that route. **How you disable EVERY possible application from being updated is too broad of a question to be answered by this community.** Most applications are only updated if you seek an update anyways.