# Windows 11 update nags after being paused

Tags: windows-update

Immediately after updating, I paused the update for 5 weeks. After 2 weeks it started nagging again, telling me that maximum period has passed, and it can't be paused anymore.

Windows update breaks its promises and continues to nag me. What to do?

---

I'll address the suggestions below.

I don't wish to update at all. When it updates, almost always something goes wrong and doesn't work afterwards, and a reboot is necessary.

I don't use the kind of apps that can be "restored" after boot.

Comment: [Continuously update your activity hours every 12-18 hours (using a scheduled task), so you essentially, are always active. Per the duplicate that says exactly that.](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/1208866#1208866) You can also accept the fact that every operating system, attempts to automatically update itself in 2023, and Windows makes this trivial by even restoring your applications after it reboots itself

Comment: Yeah, [Activity Hours](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-updates-when-you-re-away-from-your-pc-with-active-hours-in-windows-09b5376c-7647-4361-1423-c29aa692a8c4) stills exists in Windows 11 and works identically.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start updating, you may be able to pause for 5 weeks. I see that here.

However once updates have started, the maximum pause is 2 weeks. I have seen that as well on occasion when I have had to pause updates until I was able to shut down virtual machines.

Remember that Windows 11 initiates updates itself and fairly regularly.

So what you see is normal, and you must process your updates within a 2 week time span.

Windows updates have been made more mandatory with Windows 11. You cannot (on a consumer system) disable Windows 11 Updates, and restarts WILL happen from time to time (usually on Patch Tuesday) but sometimes more frequently.

You must work within Windows 11 constraints if you are going to continue to use it.

Comment: I didn't start any updates. I paused it for 5 weeks, and I expect it not to nag me for 5 weeks.

Comment: Most likely Windows itself started updates. That is completely normal and probably what happened.

Comment: I edited my answer. You cannot completely disable Windows 11 updates on a consumer system long term.