# Disable automatic restarts Windows 11

Tags: windows

I frequently have long running tasks that can take days or even weeks running on my Windows 11 pro PC. Because of this, it MUST NOT EVER restart without asking me first. My solution is to disable the windows update service, but I keep forgetting to reenable it and check for updates before starting another long running task. As such, I either never end up getting any updates, or I end up losing progress on a task that has been running for a week+.

I'm fine with getting automatic updates, but it just can't restart without asking me. I'm fine with it showing in the start menu that it needs to restart. All hours are active hours.

Comment: The only way I know how to truly disable automatic reboots on Windows 10+ is to constantly update the [active hours](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Any chance you can split the job to run part a in less than a week; part b to run in less than a week; and so on ?  Long term, life will be easier if you can do this.

Comment: I honestly keep my own system updated and very rarely if ever have it automatically reboot on me, so I can go weeks, with a pending update. But I can reschedule the reboot, but Windows, won’t let you do that forever

Comment: See answer at https://superuser.com/a/1529456/809420. It may well prevent the reboots.

Answer (score 8):

You can disable automatic restart after installing updates in the Group Policy Editor.

1. Open the Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).
2. Go to **Administrative Templates** > **Windows Components** > **Windows Update**.
3. Double-click on “No auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations”.
4. Select **Enabled**, and then select **OK**.

Comment: Done that but still restarts. Policy is ignored.

Comment: Note: This policy applies only when Automatic Updates is configured to perform scheduled installations of updates. If the "Configure Automatic Updates" policy is disabled, this policy has no effect.

Comment: What to do if this option doesn't appear in the available items for either `User Configuration` or `Computer configuration`?

Comment: If you have Windows 11 Home edition, execute the following commands in a command prompt (not PowerShell) to install Group Policy Editor:
`FOR %F IN ("%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientTools-Package~*.mum") DO (DISM /Online /NoRestart /Add-Package:"%F")
FOR %F IN ("%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ClientExtensions-Package~*.mum") DO (DISM /Online /NoRestart /Add-Package:"%F")`
Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-enable-the-gpeditmsc-on-windows-10-and-11/dbc76919-f2b5-4dec-a2b7-bcf545c34d00?page=4

Comment: I found the policies under **Administrative Templates** > **Windows Components** > **Windows Update** > **Legacy Policies** > **No auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations** and **Administrative Templates** > **Windows Components** > **Windows Update** > **Manage end user experience > Configure Automatic Updates**

Comment: Windows 11 says gpedit.msc doesn't exist.

Comment: @DmytroSukhovoy, what setting do you apply in "Configure Automatic Updates"? **Setting number 3 Auto download and notify for install**?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, enabling the option "Notify me when a restart is required to finish updating" in Windows Update > Advanced options also *implicitly* prevents the restart from occurring automatically. I would not have assumed this just from reading the text of the setting and description!

> **Notify me when a restart is required to finish updating**
>
> Show notification when your device requires a restart to finish updating

See https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8013-enable-disable-windows-update-automatic-updates-windows-10-a-post2552210.html?s=486a5969f4cef87271ea9e932484eec2#post2552210

> *In Settings, Windows Update, Advanced there is a setting "Get me up to date"* which when enabled searches frequently for updates, downloads them and restarts so you are always updated with minimum or no waiting when restarting/shutdown. *But this can restart your computer at any time without a warning before you have time to save your work!* If you usually leave your computer on to complete some tasks overnight a sudden restart will stop whatever the computer was doing. I leave it on for downloads or video rendering, so a sudden restart would interrupt this so **I never enable this setting. On the contrary I enable the "Notify me when a restart is required to finish updating" to prevent it restarting automatically.**

And for some preview of what will happen with this setting on, see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/stop-automatically-updating-my-system/1e4ab66f-c610-49a3-a627-12d4e5c75210

> First - make sure the notification is turned on for a restart
> in Settings -> Windows Update -> Advanced options
> turn on "Notify me when a restart is required to finish updating"
>
> you will get a notification that a restart is required and that Windows will restart outside active hours.
>
> if the device is not available outside active hours, you will get a notification like this
> [Image]
>
> with the option to Restart now, pick a time or snooze the notification.

although it is unclear from that whether there are limits to how far out you can select a time or how long you are allowed to snooze.  But it sounds like it will get you basically back to the status quo I remember from Win10.

Comment: At least in Windows 10, I don't believe that setting prevents automatic restarts entirely, only makes them less frequent. If you don't restart for a few days I think it will still automatically restart at some point. Not certain though.